# Does the law sets requirements for what can or cannot be inside a Company Constitution?

Tags: corporate-law, incorporation

This is for the best interest of share holders.

Say someone puts an outrageous statement in the constitution, such as making a clause that he's a permanent director on the board.

This is a general question.
To be specific, I live in Australia, and I'm referring to a proprietary limited company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes

It’s in the [Corporations Act 2001](http://www5.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/consol_act/ca2001172/).